# Best Method to Save and Read Data in Android

Tags: android, database, save, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I have an apps that using proxy to browse the url connection. But proxy host, port, username and password that i used are using hardcode. I already achieved that. But now i want to replace that hardcode with just an object that refer to the data. so the user can input the proxy that they want and can use their username and password. here is what my flow look like.

[image]

So first user can enter the name of the connection, host, port, etc that they want. And after that "save" it. And then in next activity it will read the data of that connection and if it exist, user can just to click and browse it. and if it dont, they can create the connection. If want to create it (it will back to creating connection form).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you simply want to send data to next actvity you can use `intent.putExtra();` and in next activity call `getIntent().getStringExtras();`

if you want to save data until user change it next time you can user `SharedPrefrance` as you have small amount of data.

and if your data is sensitive (want to provide more security) you can put in database or encrypt and put in database

as you are handling username and password of user you should go with sqlite database. otherwise `SharedPrefrance` was best.

**here's my pref class:**

```
public class GreetingCardData {
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_FILE     =   "greetingCardData";
    public static final String KEY_DO_NOT_SHOW      =   "doNotShow";
    public static final String KEY_CATEGORIES_JSON  =   "categoriesJson";   
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    private Editor prefsEditor;

    public GreetingCardData(Context context) {
        this.sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILE, 0);
        this.prefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    }   

    public void setDoNotShowFlag ( boolean flag ){
        prefsEditor.putBoolean( KEY_DO_NOT_SHOW, flag );
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getDoNotShowFlag(){
        return sharedPrefs.getBoolean( KEY_DO_NOT_SHOW, false );
    }

    public void setGreetingcardJson( String jsonString ){
        prefsEditor.putString( KEY_CATEGORIES_JSON, jsonString );
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getGreetingcardJsonString(){
        return sharedPrefs.getString(KEY_CATEGORIES_JSON, "");
    }    
}
```

**call from Activity:**
to save data:

```
new  GreetingCardData(ActivityMain.this).setDoNotShowFlag(flag);
```

to get data:

```
boolean flag =  new  GreetingCardData(ActivityMain.this).getDoNotShowFlag();
```

Comment: is using sharedPreference are for just temporarily? I mean when the apps is close or kill. the data was lost.

Comment: no no.. in pref data will not lost until user uninstall application. if you choose to use pref then i must suggest u should write seperate class for that to set and get data from it. it will make really easy for you to save data in pref and get it back.

Comment: thanks, i'll try it. since sharedpref is the one that i want to try before going to dbase (sqlite) way. Thanks