# Android sharedpreferences between activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hi I have a problem with Sharedpreferences because he wants to keep the data entered in the EditText in the variable and then call them in another activity to use the action but the whole time I have a problem and want to enter the program for the just the last activity of the codes 1, 2 and 3 activity where he wants to take advantage of the data.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/53l5.jpg/ - I made picture of my application

1st activity

```
   SharedPreferences kalorie = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       sharedPreferences.Editor editor = kalorie.edit();
        editor.putString("waga", waga.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("wiek", wiek.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("wzrost",wzrost.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
```

2nd Activity

```
    SharedPreferences TEA = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = TEA.edit();
                   editor1.putString("trening", trening.getText().toString());
                   editor1.putString("aeroby", aeroby.getText().toString());
                   editor.commit();
```

3th activity in this activity wants to take advantage of previously entered data into an integer textu edit and then execute them action

```
 SharedPreferences kalorie = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

int wagaValue = Integer.valueOf(kalorie.getString("waga", "0"));
int wiekValue = Integer.valueOf(kalorie.getString("wiek", "0"));
int wzrostValue = Integer.valueOf(kalorie.getString("wzrost", "0"));
int kcalwynik = (int) (((( wagaValue * 9.99 ) + ( wzrostValue * 6.25 )) - ( wiekValue * 4.92 ))+5);

txtWynik.setText(kcalwynik);

int redValue = Integer.valueOf(etreduk.getText().toString() );


SharedPreferences TEA = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

int treningValue = Integer.valueOf(TEA.getString("trening", "0"));
int aerobyValue = Integer.valueOf(TEA.getString("aeroby", "0"));

int kcalwynik1 = treningValue+aerobyValue;


int redukcja = kcalwynik + kcalwynik1;
int red1 = redukcja - redValue;

 String returnMsg = red1 + " kcal";
 txtWynik1.setText(returnMsg);
```

when the menu pops up choose the activity three deviation program has stopped

thank you for your corrections and help

1 activity (kalorie - english calories) and 2nd activity (TEA) are the activities that draw their data from the user by the EditText fields in layouts, one activity to one layout and at the end of these two activities want the retrieved data sent to the three activities to do some mathematical operations and TextView display the result.

The two activities TEA had yet radiobuttony depending how one chooses a variable x took on that value but do not know how to save the sharedpreferences radiobuttons

Comment: What is the declaration of variables kalorie and TEA? Maybe you use wrong SharedPreferences.

Comment: why don't you have a single class which wraps over SharedPreferences and takes care of all the reading from and writing to it? Check whether the SharedPreferences you are committing to, is the same one from where you are trying to read. Having a single class with named shared preference will surely make this easier.

Comment: 1 activity (kalorie - english calories) and 2nd activity (TEA)

Answer (score 0):

here's my sharedPref class as @Rajeev suggested you can write single class where you can handle all the pref. related code.

[SharedPref Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832607/best-method-to-save-and-read-data-in-android/16832983#16832983)

Comment: I did at the beginning as in this video on youtube but putInt but it did not work ... - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1tQ6dPaqLs